# Reading lines from file

Tags: c, arrays, file, dynamic, struct

I am trying to read strings and integers from a simple text file to my array. But the problem is that I get some random characters in a line in the middle of my list. It probably has to do with a newline problem, but I am not sure. The text file looks like this:

```
4
Mr Tambourine Man
Bob Dylan
1965
Dead Ringer for Love
Meat Loaf
1981
Euphoria
Loreen
2012
Love Me Now
John Legend
2016
```

The first number (4), indicates how many songs there are in the list. I have made a struct which will be able to hold the songs and dynamically allocate memory for each pointer.
Struct:

```
typedef struct Song {
    char *song;
    char *artist;
    int *year;
} Song;
```

Allocated:

```
Song *arr;
arr = (Song*)malloc(sizeof(Song));
```

Function:

```
int loadFile(char fileName[], Song *arr, int nrOf) {

    FILE *input = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (input == NULL) {
        printf("Error, the file could not load!\n");
    } else {
        int i = 0;
        fscanf(input, "%d\n", &nrOf);

        for (int i = 0; i < nrOf; i++) {
            arr[i].song = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
            arr[i].artist = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
            arr[i].year = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
            fgets(arr[i].song, 100, input);
            fgets(arr[i].artist, 100, input);
            fscanf(input, "%d\n", arr[i].year);
        }
        printf("The file is now ready.\n");
        fclose(input);
    }

    return nrOf;
}
```

Are you able to find the problem? Or do you have a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
arr[i].song = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
arr[i].artist = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

You are only allocating buffers of size `1`, there's no scaling. This gives you undefined behavior when you overrun the buffers by loading more data into them than they can hold.

I would expect those to read:

```
arr[i].song = malloc(100);
```

and so on. Note that no cast is necessary, and `sizeof (char)` is always 1.

Also, this:

```
arr[i].year = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

is super-strange. There's absolutely no reason to dynamically allocate a single integer, just make the field an `int` and store the value there directly.

Answer (score 1):

- **First Issue:**

  ```
  arr[i].song = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
  arr[i].artist = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
  ```

  Are only allocating 1 byte for your `char*` pointers, `song` and `artist`. You can allocate a size for this:

  ```
  arr[i].song = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char)); /* or malloc(100) */
  arr[i].artist = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
  ```

  Or you can simply `malloc()` enough space from you buffer:

  ```
  char buffer[100];
  fgets(buffer, 100, input);
  /* check for failure, remove newline */
  arr[i].song = malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
  /* check error from malloc */
  strcpy(arr[i].song, buffer);
  ```

  Or even use [`strdup()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup):

  ```
  arr[i].song = strdup(buffer);
  ```

  Which is a substitute for `malloc()`/`strcpy()`.

  **Note:** You can also read [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).
- **Second Issue:**

  Your current `struct`:

  ```
  typedef struct Song {
      char *song;
      char *artist;
      int *year;
  } Song;
  ```

  Can be simplified to:

  ```
  typedef struct {
      char *song;
      char *artist;
      int year;
  } Song;
  ```

  Because `year` does not need to be a pointer. Easier to manage if its just an `int`. This avoids having to do allocations like:

  ```
  arr[i].year = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  ```
- **Other Recommendations:**
  You should check the return of `fscanf()` and `fgets()` as its safe to do this. It helps just incase your file will have incorrect data. This goes the same for `malloc()`, which can return `NULL` is unsuccessfully allocated on the heap.

Here is some code with the above considerations in mind:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 100

typedef struct {
    char *song;
    char *artist;
    int year;
} Song;

Song *create_array(FILE *input, int *nrof);
void load_data(Song *arr, FILE *input, int nrof);
void print_free_data(Song *arr, int nrof);
void get_buffer(char buffer[], FILE *input);

int main(void) {
    FILE *input;
    Song *arr;
    int nrof;

    input = fopen("artist.txt", "r");
    if (input == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    arr = create_array(input, &nrof);

    load_data(arr, input, nrof);

    print_free_data(arr, nrof);

    fclose(input);

    return 0;
}

Song *create_array(FILE *input, int *nrof) {
    Song *arr;

    if (fscanf(input, "%d ", nrof) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find number of songs\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    arr = malloc(*nrof * sizeof(*arr));
    if (arr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate %d spaces for array\n", *nrof);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return arr;
}

void load_data(Song *arr, FILE *input, int nrof) {
    char buffer[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < nrof; i++) {
        get_buffer(buffer, input);
        arr[i].song = malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
        if (arr[i].song == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate song\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy(arr[i].song, buffer);

        get_buffer(buffer, input);
        arr[i].artist = malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
        if (arr[i].artist == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate artist\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy(arr[i].artist, buffer);

        if (fscanf(input, "%d ", &arr[i].year) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find year for Song: %s Album: %s\n", 
                             arr[i].song, arr[i].artist);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

void get_buffer(char buffer[], FILE *input) {
    size_t slen;

    if (fgets(buffer, SIZE, input) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error from fgets(), line not read\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    slen = strlen(buffer);
    if (slen > 0 && buffer[slen-1] == '\n') {
        buffer[slen-1] = '\0';
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Too many characters entered\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void print_free_data(Song *arr, int nrof) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nrof; i++) {
        printf("%s\n%s\n%d\n\n", arr[i].song, arr[i].artist, arr[i].year);

        free(arr[i].song);
        arr[i].song = NULL;

        free(arr[i].artist);
        arr[i].artist = NULL;
    }

    free(arr);
    arr = NULL;
}
```

Which Outputs correct data:

```
Mr Tambourine Man
Bob Dylan
1965

Dead Ringer for Love
Meat Loaf
1981

Euphoria
Loreen
2012

Love Me Now
John Legend
2016
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for this detailed answer :D I will make some changes

Answer (score 1):

Your memory allocation is incorrect.  The structure should have `char` arrays for the song and artist names and an `int` for the year, and you should modify your API to return the array and its size to the caller:

```
int loadFile(const char *fileName, Song **arr, int *numberp);
```

Here is a corrected and simplified of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Song {
    char song[100];
    char artist[100];
    int year;
} Song;

/* call as
   if (loadFile(fileName, &songs, &songs_size) < 0) {
       // deal with error...
   }
*/

int loadFile(const char *fileName, Song **arrp, int *numberp) {
    FILE *input;
    Song *arr;
    int i, nrOf;

    input = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (input == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s\n", filename);
        return -1;
    } else {
        if (fscanf(input, "%d\n", &nrOf) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: missing number of items\n", filename);
            fclose(intput);
            return -1;
        }
        arr = calloc(sizeof(*arr), nrOf);
        if (arr == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory for %d items\n", nrOf);
            fclose(intput);
            return -1;
        }    
        for (int i = 0; i < nrOf; i++) {
            char cc;
            if (fscanf(input, "%99[^\n]%*c%99[^\n]%*c%d%c",
                       sarr[i].song, arr[i].artist,
                       &arr[i].year, &cc) != 4 || cc != '\n') {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: invalid format for item %d\n",
                        filename, i);
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("The file is now ready.\n");
        fclose(input);
        *arrp = arr;
        *numberp = i;
        return i;
    }
}
```